# How to draw text on image with semi transparent background in Xamarin iOS?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have an UIImage I would like to draw text on image. I would like it to look like this:
[image]

I am drawing text with this code:

```cs
private static UIImage DrawText(UIImage uiImage, string sText, UIColor textColor, int iFontSize)
{
    nfloat fWidth = uiImage.Size.Width;
    nfloat fHeight = uiImage.Size.Height;

    using (CGBitmapContext ctx = new CGBitmapContext(IntPtr.Zero, (nint)fWidth, (nint)fHeight, 8, 4 * (nint)fWidth, CGColorSpace.CreateDeviceRGB(), CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedFirst))
    {
        ctx.DrawImage(new CGRect(0, 0, (double)fWidth, (double)fHeight), uiImage.CGImage);

        ctx.SelectFont("Helvetica", iFontSize, CGTextEncoding.MacRoman);

        nfloat fRed, fGreen, fBlue, fAlpha;
        textColor.GetRGBA(out fRed, out fGreen, out fBlue, out fAlpha);
        ctx.SetFillColor(fRed, fGreen, fBlue, fAlpha);

        ctx.SetTextDrawingMode(CGTextDrawingMode.Fill);
        ctx.ShowTextAtPoint(fWidth / 4, fHeight / 10, sText);

        return UIImage.FromImage(ctx.ToImage());
    }
}
```

It draws text correctly. Problem is it doesn't have grey rectangle around it that fills space with grey. How can I accomplish this?